# Distribution with Integral - correct?

Tags: probability

*Given*$$\Bbb P(X=k)=\frac{1}{2^n} \binom{n}{k}$$
*I want to calculate the distribution* $F_X(t)$.

*As far as I know it is* $$\begin{align}F_X(t) & =\int_0^t\frac{1}{2^n} \binom{n}{k}dk \\ &= \int_0^t\frac{1}{2^n}\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} dk \\ &\approx \int_{0}^t\frac{1}{2^n}\frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}(\frac{n}{e})^n}{\sqrt{2\pi k}(\frac{k}{e})^k{\sqrt{2\pi (n-k)}(\frac{(n-k)}{e})^{n-k}}}dk \\ &= \int_{0}^t\frac{\sqrt{ n}\cdot n^n}{\sqrt{k}\cdot k^k{\sqrt{2\pi (n-k)}(n-k)^{n-k}}}dk\end{align}$$

Howcan I simplyfy it or is it wrong ?

Comment: Oh my goodness... perhaps double check your definition of $F_X(t)$. Namely, $F_X(t) = P(X \le t)$. You do not have a PDF so you don't need to use an integral. Think also about what values $X$ can take; specifically, $P(X = k) = \frac{1}{2^n} \binom{n}{k}$ does not hold for all real $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have $f(k) = \binom{n}{k}/2^n$, which would naturally be defined for all integer $k \in [0,n]$, and indeed,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n f(k) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}/2^n = 2^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} = 1
$$
by the Binomial Theorem.

Hence,
$$
F(k) = \mathbb{P}[X \le k] = \sum_{i=0}^k f(k) = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{i=0}^k \binom{n}{k}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

This distribution looks like it's discrete. Try using a sum instead of an integral and see if there's a closed form.

${\sum_{k=0}^{j<=n}{\frac{1}{2^n}{n\choose k}}}$